# Find and replace special character ":" in MS Word 2013

Tags: ms-word, wildcard, word-2013

I am having a Word document (MS Word 2013) with several timing numbers like shown below:

```
(00:03)
(00:18)
(11:39)
```

And I am using Wildcards and using this pattern, shown below:

```
\(*:*\)
```

But the problem is that it also includes this type of text, shown below:

```
(text)
(drumroll)
```

I want to remove only numbers, not text. How to deal with this? Does anyone knows which pattern to use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
\([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\)
```

Atleast upto 2010 above regex works.

In 2013 you may need to escape the : with \ so try this instead

```
\([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\)
```

Comment: Thanks mate!! That's working very nicely!! Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use these sites to practice and understand RegExp

- https://regex101.com/
- http://regexr.com/

Try to use this pattern in your case. I have tested it in the links above, not MS Word

```
\(\d\d:\d\d\)
```

Comment: Liem To, Thanks Mate for taking the time but the above pattern didn't work. Can you help me with some other pattern? Thank you again!!

Comment: I have tried with the pattern suggested by Rahul. It works.

Comment: My pattern only works with standard RegExp. I have tested it in the mentioned links but not MS Word.